# How do I make Outlook-addins maintain URL fragments to support single page applications?

Tags: ms-office, single-page-application, outlook-addin

I've found that when launching an Outlook add-in, the URL that you configure in the manifest does not persist the fragment URL and this breaks Single Page Applications (SPAs). It works fine if you are just trying to go to the default route of the SPA e.g. index.html but if you try and go directly to a fragment URL (route) within the app then it doesn't work e.g. index.html#mypage

The `index.html#mypage` actually gets changed to this:
`index.html?et=&_host_Info=Outlook|Web|1…_1480636166782|ocii1|https://outlook.office.com/owa/?realm=XYZ.com#&_serializer_version=1mypage&_xdm_Info=-133b2041_-3d735892_1480636166782|ocii1|https://outlook.office.com/owa/?realm=XYZ.com`

Further explanation of the issue can be found here:
https://camerondwyer.wordpress.com/2016/12/02/issues-launching-outlook-add-ins-directly-to-a-spa-route-using-fragment-urls/

Moving to HTML5 style URLs is not currently an option for me so routing within the SPA needs to use the Fragment URL (hashbang). I imagine anyone trying to start an add-in and pass parameters in the URL would be seeing a similar problem.